# Converting c to php

Tags: php, c, qt, gd

Hi I have the following code for a CLI working, done in C. I want now to translate it in PHP, but I am stuck on the color converting. Any clues?

```
for (size_t y = 0; y < targetHeight; y++) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < targetWidth; x++) {
        // Convertimos el color

        png::rgba_pixel_16 pixel = renderImage[y][x];

        uint alpha = pixel.alpha / 256;

        if (alpha > 0) {

            minX = minX < x ? minX : x;
            maxX = maxX > x ? maxX : x;
            minY = minY < y ? minY : y;
            maxY = maxY > y ? maxY : y;

            jpgImage->setPixel(x, y, (pixel.red/256 << 16) + (pixel.green/256 << 8) + pixel.blue/256 ) ;

            uint mP = mapImage->pixel(x, y);

            mapImage->setPixel(x, y, mP + (alpha<<16)  );

        }
    }
}
```

The part am stuck with is the pixel.red << 16 thing, where I cannot get the right colors from the image and convert them properly using PHP.

Here's the PHP code so far:

```
for ($y = 0; $y < HEIGHT; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < WIDTH; $x++) {
        // Convertimos el color

        $pixel = imagecolorat($render_img, $x, $y);
        //$pixel = imagecolorat($render_img, $y, $x);

        $rgba = imagecolorsforindex($render_img, $pixel);
        $currentAlpha = $rgba['alpha']/256;
        //$alpha = pixel.alpha / 256;

        if ($currentAlpha > 0) {

            $minX = $minX < $x ? $minX : $x;
            $maxX = $maxX > $x ? $maxX : $x;
            $minY = $minY < $y ? $minY : $y;
            $maxY = $maxY > $y ? $maxY : $y;

            imagesetpixel ($result_jpg_image, $x, $y, ($rgba['red']/256<<16) + ($rgba['green']/256<<8) + ($rgba['blue']/256));
            //imagesetpixel ($result_jpg_image, $x, $y, ($rgba['red'] << 16) + ($rgba['green'] << 8) + ($rgba['blue']));
            //jpgImage->setPixel(x, y, (pixel.red/256 << 16) + (pixel.green/256 << 8) + pixel.blue/256 ) ;

            $pixel = imagecolorat($zMap, $x, $y);
            imagesetpixel ($zMap, $x, $y, ($pixel + $currentAlpha<<16));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your PHP code that you have started.

Comment: that shifts the red byte left 16 bits. if you think of a color as a hexidecimal number given by 0xRRGGBB and each hexgit is 4 bits, then you should be able to see what it's doing. php supports bit shifting. where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure dividing the RGB value by 256 is giving you the desired effect.

Try:

```
imagesetpixel($result_jpg_image, $x, $y,
              ($rgba['red']<<16) + ($rgba['green']<<8) + ($rgba['blue']));
```

I'm not sure if you are trying to apply some color algorithm but dividing the RGB values by 256 and then left shifting the resulting float is giving you `0` in PHP.

The above line of code I gave you just sets the pixel back to the same color.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, I get the same results. The 256 division is because I just copied the C code which includes that division.

Comment: Are `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` actually set correctly?  Also how about `$zMap`?  I just realized also the call to [imagesetpixel()](http://php.net/imagesetpixel) is also incorrect.  The 4th parameter is a color resource created by [imagecolorallocate()](http://php.net/imagecolorallocate).

Comment: HEIGHT and WIDTH are constants, yes they are set so that they match the image. The 4th parameter is a color resource, right, so it's a pixel. Where do you see the error?

Comment: You have to call `imagecolorallocate()` with an RGB value and pass that resource to `imagesetpixel()`.  It won't work passing a 32 bit color value.  See http://php.net/imagesetpixel#refsect1-function.imagesetpixel-examples